# Fetching doctrine results based on model instance

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine

I have a Symfony2 form that is returning submitted data as a Doctrine2 model with the fields populated. I am trying to then fetch all entities from the database that match the values set in the model.

Normally I would use the `findBy` function on the doctrine repository. However, that is expecting an associative array containing the search criteria.

Is there another function similar to `findBy` where I can pass a populated model as the search criteria?

Comment: Nope.  Easy enough to add custom queries to a repository.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would have to write your [own repository method](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/doctrine.html#custom-repository-classes) to handle something like that.  You could pass it an object, but you would have to strip out the details you need for your query.

something like:

```
 public function findBySomeOtherCriteria( AcmeBundle\Entity\Trythis $entity )
 {
      $param1 = $entity->getParam1();
      $param2 = $entity->getParam2();

      $query = $this->getEntityManager()->createQuery( 
          'select a
          from AcmeBundle\Entity\Adifferentone a
          where a.param1 = :param1
          and a.param2 = :param2
          ' )->setParameters( array( 'param1' => $param1, 'param2' => $param2 );
     return $query->getResult();
 }
```